# Is it possible to connect Grafana to postgres database based on a remote server without expose database port?

Tags: postgresql, server, configuration, connection, grafana

I am looking for a solution. I wan't to connect my postgres database to grafana but, both services are not on the same server and i don't wan't to expose my database.

I tought that ssh tunneling could be a good solution, but there is no paramaters on Grafana UI.

Someone had already solved this problem ? Or do you have some ideas ?

**Thanks!**